# how to restrict growable text field upto 5 line in adobe liveCycle form

Tags: javascript, forms, livecycle, livecycle-designer, lcds

![enter image description here][1]1.

Need Help in Adobe Livecycle user entered growable text field

In Adobe Livecycle tool, I have to restrict user to enter maximum of 5 line. Note : This is Growable User Entered Text Field so we cant fixed with layout.

Please Help Guys your quick action will be appriciable.

Many Thanks !!

Comment: Please refer this link for details desc with screen shot :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28831324/4456889

Answer (score 0):

You *could* add XML for the document to do this.

Look for this in the XML Source:

```
<field name="tfWhateverYouNamedTheField"
```

And add this if the caption is on top or bottom:

```
maxH="33.81mm"
```

or this if the caption is on left or right:

```
maxH="25.4mm"
```

That will cap the size at 5 lines for 10pt Myriad Pro. If you're using a different size/font, adjust accordingly.